# Does iOS PhoneGap onSuccess() callback return synchronously when cordova.exec() is done?

Tags: cordova

My iOS PhoneGap application works fine with PhoneGap 2.2.0, but does not work with PhoneGap 2.3.0+.
The code snippet below behaves differently in iPhone Simulator 6.1 with PhoneGap 2.2.0 and 2.3.0+:

```
var msg = "N/A";

EchoSession.prototype.getMessage = function() {
    cordova.exec(onSuccess, onFail, "Echo", "echo", "hello-world");
    console.log("message: " + msg);
    return msg;
};

function onSuccess(ret)
{
    console.log("onSuccess: ret is " + ret);
    msg = "output: " + ret;
}
```

Where `Echo` is the PhoneGap Plugin, `Echo.echo(param)` simply returns the value of param passed to it.

With PhoneGap 2.2.0, `getMessage()` returns the expected result, however, with PhoneGap 2.3.0+, `getMessage()` returns "N/A", which is the default value of 'msg', because the "return msg" statement is reached before the onSuccess() callback is done.
I suspect the onSuccess() callback is returned synchronously when cordova.exec() is done in PhoneGap 2.2.0, but in PhoneGap 2.3.0+, the onSuccess() callback is asynchronous.

Do you guys have any thought on the issue?
Is there any changes in PhoneGap 2.3.0 for iOS that could cause the behavior difference?
Can I make the `onSuccess()` callback synchronous in PhoneGap 2.3.0+ for iOS?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one can help you

make sure you already define your plugin in your config.xml

```
<feature name="CustomPlugin">
      <param name="ios-package" value="CustomPlugin" />
</feature>
```

Implementing the plug-in by using Objective-C code

CustomPlugin.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <Cordova/CDV.h>

@interface CustomPlugin : CDVPlugin

- (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command;

@end
```

CustomPlugin.m

```
#import "CustomPlugin.h"

    @implementation CustomPlugin

    - (void)sayHello:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command{

        NSString *responseString =
            [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello World, %@", [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]];

        CDVPluginResult *pluginResult =
            [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:responseString];

        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
    }

    @end
```

Calling a plug-in from JavaScript

```
function initial(){
    var name = $("#NameInput").val();
    cordova.exec(sayHelloSuccess, sayHelloFailure, "CustomPlugin", "sayHello", [name]);
}

function sayHelloSuccess(data){
    alert("OK: " + data);
}

function sayHelloFailure(data){
    alert("FAIL: " + data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I've already implemented the `Echo` plugin, and everything works fine with PhoneGap 2.2.0. My question is why the same application does not work with PhoneGap 2.3.0+, and is there any changes in handling onSuccess() callback inside PhoneGap 2.3.0+ ?

Comment: I think this code can be run on cordova v2 and v3. My current cordova version is 3.4. It works fine.